# Double Integral Polar Coordinates in terms of r(θ)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Bit of trouble with the following problem:

> $\int\int_R 1 \,\mathrm{d}A$, where $0 \le r \le r(\theta)$. $r(\theta) = 8 − \sin(\theta) + 2 \sin(3\theta) + 2 \sin(5\theta)−\sin(7\theta) + 3 \cos(2\theta)−2 \cos(4\theta).$

So, I set up my integrals as: 
$\int_0^{2π}\int_0^{r(\theta)} r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta$.

First, integrating with respect to $r$, you get $\frac{1}{2}(r(\theta))^2$, but when you integrate this with respect to $\theta$, it becomes a tricky integral.

Help please?

Comment: Perhaps rewrite $\cos \theta = \frac{e^{i\theta} + e^{-i \theta}}{2}$ and $\sin \theta = \frac{e^{i \theta} - e^{-i \theta}}{2i}$? It may make $r^2$ a bit easier to simplify.

Comment: @MyGlasses don't quite understand your comment... could you explain a little more please?

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{r\left(\theta\right)}r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{1}{2}\left(r(\theta)\right)^{2}\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(8-\sin\theta+2\sin3\theta+2\sin5\theta-\sin7\theta+3\cos2\theta-2\cos4\theta\right)^{2}\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Now, this expands to many terms, but all of the cross terms turn out to have integral zero.

For $8$ and a single trig function, we have things like $\int_{0}^{2\pi}2*8\left(-\sin7\theta\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta=0$ since we go through $7$ periods of sine and everything cancels out.

For products of two different trig functions, we can use the [product to sum formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)  to reduce everything to sums of individual trig functions. For example, $\int_{0}^{2\pi}2*\left(2\sin5\theta\right)\left(3\cos2\theta\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta=12\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin7\theta+\sin3\theta\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ and each part has integral zero.

The only terms that remain are the squares of the terms of $r(\theta)$. But, even then, things simplify. For example, $\sin^{2}3\theta=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos6\theta$ but the $\cos6\theta$ part integrates to $0$. Every square of a trig function just becomes $\frac12$ in that way because of the formulas for $\cos 2x$.

Therefore, the original integral reduces to:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(8^{2}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2}}{2}+\frac{2^{2}}{2}+\frac{2^{2}}{2}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2}}{2}+\frac{3^{2}}{2}+\frac{\left(-2\right)^{2}}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{128+1+4+4+1+9+4}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{151}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{151}{2}\pi\text{.}$$